# Codeigniter dynamic configuration

Tags: codeigniter

How do I let users set the database configuration for a new CI install?

My intention is to have a form that allows them to enter the data then either generate a new config file or to set the options in the database.php file.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to create a database config file. Here's how I do it:

Create a "dummy" config file by copying  a real one, and use values that look something like this:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '__HOSTNAME__';
$db['default']['username'] = '__USERNAME__';
$db['default']['password'] = '__PASSWORD__';
$db['default']['database'] = '__DATABASE__';
```

Have the user complete the installation form, and verify all the data by testing a database connection. Next, use `file_get_contents()` to grab the content of the "dummy" config file, use a simple `str_replace()` to rewrite the values with the ones the user provided, then write the new content to your real config file overwriting the entire thing.

Here's part of the actual code I'm using for *creating* the file, just to get an idea. Bear in mind that I'm running this on a totally separate CI installation (the "installer"), and this is not a copy/paste example:

```
// Write the database configuration file
$config = array(
    'hostname',
    'username',
    'password',
    'database',
);

$data = file_get_contents(APPPATH.'config/dummy_database.php');
$file = '../private/config/database.php';

// Oops! Just caught this after posting: str_replace() accepts arrays.
// TODO: Use the array method instead of a loop!
foreach ($config as $item)
{
    $data = str_replace('____'.strtoupper($item).'____', mysql_escape_string($this->data[$item]), $data);
}
if (write_file($file, $data))
{
    $this->message('Database configuration file was written!', 'success');
    @chmod($file, 0644);
    {
        if (is_really_writable($file))
        {
            $this->message('The database configuration is still writable, make sure to set permissions to <code>0644</code>!', 'notice');
        }
    }
}
else
{
    $this->message('Could not write the database configuration file!');
    redirect('step_4');
}
```

This retains the original copy of the "dummy" config file. You could use the same logic for editing, just read the current config values for anything the user has not changed and do the same string replacement technique.

Comment: So you have one CI installation write the db config for another installation?

Comment: Yes, because I'm using an "installer" (separate app), which gets deleted afterwards. You can use this same logic to update your config file though as well, from the same application.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting your concept, but I'm not understanding where you are getting $this->data[$item] from. Also, I can't change permissions on the original database config file to overwrite it. CI is not allowing me to use chmod.

Comment: Yeah chmod usually fails for me too, I have to go in via FTP and set the permissions, that's usually step 3 of my installer - checking the permissions before attempting to write the file, this code I gave you is just running that check again. However, I did mention that this was only **part** of ***my** actual code* and **not** to take it verbatim. I was pretty sure you were asking for the **concept** because I didn't see any code in your question, you just asked if it was possible. `$this->data` is an array I use to store the installation details in the installer controller.

Comment: So let me see if I understand; You have your user download a package that contains 2 CI apps. Then you use one app to configure the other and then delete the first app? Do you do this all within CI or due you have some outside scripts that you use as well? Because I was thinking of doing something similar, but just writing the installer from scratch. I just keep having problems with the permissions.

Comment: That's correct, I have my real app and installer app side by side, then the installer is deleted. I can't even run the real app until it's set up by the installer, as it will require db connection details and an encryption key set. (BTW make sure to allow the installer app in your .htaccess if using one) I check all the files that need to be writable, attempt to do it with the installer, and failing that - prompt the user to do it themselves before continuing. There's no way around that in many cases.

Comment: @WesleyMurch let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2676/discussion-between-pelachile-and-wesley-murch)